# Undefined control sequence \State \For \While

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode, algorithmic

I am trying to write a pseudo code in MiKTeX. I have used `\usepackage{algorithm}` 
`\usepackage{algorithmic}` but I get:

> Undefined control sequence' for every structure (\State, \While, \For, \If).

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{PSO}
\label{pseudoPSO}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Initialize a population of particles with random values positions and velocities from \textit{D} dimensions in the search space
\WHILE{Termination condition not reached} 
\For{ Each particle \textit{i}}
    \State Adapt velocity of the particle using Equation \ref{eq:1}
    \State Update the position of the particle using Equation \ref{eq:2}
    \State Evaluate the fitness {$f(\overrightarrow{X}_i)$}
    \If{\begin{equation}f(\overrightarrow{X}_i)<f(\overrightarrow{P}_i)\end    {equation} 
        \begin{equation}\overrightarrow{P}_i \gets \overrightarrow{X}_i\end{equation}
    \EndIf
    \If{\begin{equation}f(\overrightarrow{X}_i)<f(\overrightarrow{P}_g)\end{equation} 
        \begin{equation}\overrightarrow{P}_g \gets \overrightarrow{X}_i\end{equation}
    \EndIf
\EndFor
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're loading `algorithmic`, but using the syntax of `algpseudocode`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{PSO}
\label{pseudoPSO}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Initialize a population of particles with random values positions
       and velocities from \textit{D} dimensions in the search space
\While{Termination condition not reached}
\For{Each particle $i$}
    \State Adapt velocity of the particle using Equation \ref{eq:1}
    \State Update the position of the particle using Equation \ref{eq:2}
    \State Evaluate the fitness {$f(\overrightarrow{X}_i)$}
    \If{$f(\overrightarrow{X}_i)<f(\overrightarrow{P}_i)$}
       \State $\overrightarrow{P}_i \gets \overrightarrow{X}_i$
    \EndIf
    \If{$f(\overrightarrow{X}_i)<f(\overrightarrow{P}_g)$}
       \State $\overrightarrow{P}_g \gets \overrightarrow{X}_i$
    \EndIf
\EndFor
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't make much sense using `equation` inside an algorithm, especially in the argument of `\If`. Note that `\WHILE` and `\ENDWHILE` should be `\While` and `\EndWhile`.

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly now, thank you. I used `equation` when trying to get rid of the errors.

Comment: The above code is generating `\caption outside float. \caption`, at the 5th line.

Comment: @GuruSwaroop I tried it again and it runs without problems.

Comment: @erreg Can you help me with this issue : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317611/error-caption-outside-float-inside-algorithm

Comment: @GuruSwaroop I get no error with that code either.

Comment: I just want to point that in the beginning it doesn't work for me. But, I take copy-past the above code and put it in separate file, then it starts to download the package. Then, I back to my file, it works well except that \BState doesn't work in this, so I changed it to \State. Now, it works well! (this comment for anyone who has still this problem)